# Unexplained dip in LCD screen brightness

Tags: voltage, current, lcd

I am using a [16x2 I2C LCD module](https://robu.in/product/serial-lcd1602-iici2c-blue-backlight/?gclid=Cj0KCQiA4uCcBhDdARIsAH5jyUn146mB5TxjQmTbmKKmvYbcizon8t6M6TCYqal-qd4mJda8-j5yRTgaAjFyEALw_wcB) in my Arduino project. The schematic is shown below:

[image: Schematic]

My power supply is shown below:

[image: Power Supply]

It was working fine till recently, but since some changes done which should affect the power consumption of the motor involved (increase), I am noticing a dip in the brightness of the LCD each time the motor switches on. I am using a [Buck converter](https://robu.in/product/lm2596s-dc-dc-buck-converter-power-supply/?gclid=Cj0KCQiA4uCcBhDdARIsAH5jyUmdNgg7lAL_tKhwiPnzBuJpWwMWlBSOs_HGABOOuoDx4C7oLQ-ze3AaAsg_EALw_wcB) which steps down the 12 V of the Arduino suitable 5 V. I have checked the voltage at the output of this buck converter and it is stable even when the motor is running. Interestingly If I connect the multimeter probes while the motor is running the sensor involved stops printing the readings  to the screen.

I don't understand the reason for the dip in screen brightness when the voltage output of the  buck converter doesn't shift. Polarity is also protected by diode.

---

**Edit 1:**
Ok, interesting development, I checked voltage directly at the LCD. While the Buck converter output is still just 5.05 V and doesn't budge with motor on or off, the voltage going to the LCD for some reason is just 4.73 V and drops further to 4.5 V when the motor starts. Why is that hapenning?

**Edit 2:**
Buck converter's output is -5.05 V when it is not connected to the system. Otherwise -4.89 V. When motor on, it drops to 4.5 V, rises to 4.7 V, fluctuates between 4.6 V and 4.77 V.

I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: How did you verify the stability of the voltage? is the backlight of the LCD driven from the 12V or the 5V?

Comment: @po.pe LCD is driven by 5V from the Arduino which is directly connected to the %v of the buck convertor where I connected my probes. Also for some reason after I switch off the machine if I touch some exposed wiring there is slight shock. Is that usual?

Comment: @po.pe Ok, interesting development, I checked voltage directly at the LCD. Whle the Buck convertor output is still just 5.05 and doesn't budge with motor on or off, the voltage going to the LCD for some reason is just 4.73 and drops further to 4.5 when the motor starts. Why is that hapenning??

Comment: @po.pe Have added another update to question, please check

Comment: Well I guess the motor is quite a load on your supply and the buck converter probably doesn't really like that. What capacitances do you have to support your motor driving voltage?

Comment: For your schematic, I recommend you use labels instead of drawing long lines that cross over. The dotted line tool is also useful for creating areas.

Comment: Some parts of your schematic are very hard to follow. There are lines that zig-zag where they should be straightened out and connected with the shortest lines possible. And some values are missing or obscured, particularly capacitors.

Comment: @PStechPaul capacitors are 25V 1000uF

Comment: @DribbleNibble - We are glad that your question has been answered, but please do not remove important information from your question now that you don't need it. Part of the purpose of Stack Exchange is to collect question & answer pairs for future readers. For that reason, questions must be left in the state that related to the answers given - otherwise they make no sense for future readers. Therefore I have reversed (rolled-back) your edit which removed details from the question. Please do not delete information from the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the motor turns on, there will be a large inrush current. When current increases, so does the impedance of your wires or traces. As the impedence increases, this limits the amount of power that can be transmitted (it also heats up the traces/wires as energy is dissipated).

You can try to resolve this using a few techniques, off the top of my head:

1. Increase the sizes of the traces/wires all the way from your power source to your motor.
2. Try using a separate power supply for the motor (edit: I did say different buck, but I see now that it’s a 12V motor)
3. Try using a big ass capacitor right next to the motor (though, you’ll probably have limited success).
4. Try adding capacitors near your other components, too, as close as possible.

By the way, your schematic would be much easier to read if you used labels and created areas (dashed line tool). If it were easier to read, you might get more answers.

---

Edit: I see the following does not apply, since the motor is connected to 12V.

Buck modules also tend to be quite sensitive when you’re exposing them to a high inrush current caused by an inductive load; I’ve noticed that many have a dip in voltage as current increases (even if it’s within advertised limits).

6. Change the motor to a different one so that the motor voltage matches that of the power source, so you don’t need a buck.
7. Reduce the voltage of the main supply so you don’t need a buck for the motor.

Comment: Thanks...I think you are right about my wires, I know they are low gauge for this job. My buck converter doesn't power the motor, the motor and the valve (heavier loads) are powered directly by the 12V 16A power supply. The same power supply goes through a diode into the buck convertor which steps it down to 5V and powers the Arduino, the 5V 1 channel relay module, the sensor. I think I will check my wiring again and check whther my trace widths are suitable.

Comment: Ah, I see. Normally you’d connect a 12V power symbol as close to the motor as you can (so the supply voltage is clear), rather than drawing a long line. I reckon that there could also be high current impedance either within the power supply itself, or if the buck and the motor share the same supply wire, then that could be the bottleneck. You may want to try a separate power supply for the motors. Or, a beefier power supply.